# Loop with KSH or BASH from ls + pattern

Tags: linux, ksh

I'm making korn shell script that tries to do some tasks looping from an ls and a filename pattern.

If I hardcode the pattern inside the script then it works:

```
for my_archive in ls FAC*
do
echo $my_archive
done
```

But if I send the pattern by param, only gives me the first occurrence:

```
for my_archive in ls $1
 do
  echo $my_archive
 done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't want "ls" in there

I'm guessing you call your function like this

```
myfunc FAC*
```

In that case, the shell expands the pattern **before** invoking the function. So, you actually have something like this:

```
myfunc FAC1 FAC2 FAC3 ...
```

When you use $1, you just pick the first file and ignore the rest

In your function, use this:

```
function myfunc {
    for my_archive in "$@"; do
        echo "$my_archive"
    done
}
```

Using the quotes exactly as I have them will protect any files with spaces in the name.

Answer (score 1):

First inorder to loop through files in directory using `for` no `ls` is required. Simple wildcard "*" will expand into the list of files within the directory.

```
for my_archive in FAC*
do
echo $my_archive
done
```

would give outputs as

```
FACfoo
FACbar
FAC123
```

and so on

now the second code changes as

```
for my_archive in $1
 do
  echo $my_archive
 done
```

if the code is saved as `test, run the code as

`test "FAC*"`
so that the wildcard is expanded before the excecution of the script.